# QPlace a pnr to multiple Sabre queues in one step

Tags: soap, sabre

I would like to QPlace a named pnr onto multiple queues.
The documentation for QueuePlaceLLSRQ_v2.0.4 seems to indicate that this is possible by repeating QueueIdentifier element but I always get errors

```
<QueueInfo>
<!--Mandatory-->
<!--Repeat Factor=0-3-->
...
<QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="IPCC1" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" Number="400" Name="ABC123"/>
```

REQUEST AND RESPONSE 1:

```
 <QueuePlaceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.4">
      <QueueInfo>
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" Number="204" />
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" Number="205" />
        <UniqueID ID="CIATDK" />
      </QueueInfo>
    </QueuePlaceRQ>


 <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2020-02-06T05:02:09-06:00">
          <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            <stl:Message>INVALID FORMAT</stl:Message>
            <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
          </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
      </stl:ApplicationResults>
```

REQUEST AND RESPONSE 2:

```
<QueuePlaceRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.4">
      <QueueInfo>
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" Number="204" />
        <UniqueID ID="ESVDGN" />
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="11" Number="205" />
        <UniqueID ID="ESVDGN" />
      </QueueInfo>
    </QueuePlaceRQ>


<stl:SystemSpecificResults>
<stl:Message>cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'QueueIdentifier'. One of '{"http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10":UniqueID}' is expected.</stl:Message>
<stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
</stl:SystemSpecificResults>
```

REQUEST & RESPONSE 3 (seems to be on-queue only, cannot use named pnr):

```
<QueuePlaceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.0.4">
      <MultiQueuePlace>
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="35" Number="205" />
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="35" Number="206" />
      </MultiQueuePlace>
    </QueuePlaceRQ>


    <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2020-02-06T05:09:53-06:00">
          <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            <stl:Message>NO PNR IN AAA</stl:Message>
            <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
          </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
      </stl:ApplicationResults>
```

Comment: Response 3, is due to after a PNR is placed on a queue, it is removed from the workspace. When the second queue place is executed, the PNR is no longer open.  

I don't have an answer for you yet, just pointing that out

Comment: In example 3, I don't see that you have <UniqueID ID="ESVDGN" /> or any reference to the PNR. Are you first executing the TravelItineraryReadLLSRQ API to display the PNR?

Comment: So after getting in touch with Sabre support , "REQUEST & RESPONSE 3" is the correct way but you must have the pnr in your workarea, you cannot specify a different pnr
However the pnr is not left on the original queue, which to me makes this a QueueMove queue rather than a QueuePlace.

I was using QueueMoveLLSRQ to move 1 named pnr to a new queue ( but I then wanted to move to multiple queues)
I now use QueuePlaceLLSRQ to move workarea pnr to multiple queues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct method is in the question as "REQUEST & RESPONSE 3", but you must have a pnr in your workarea. If you also wish the pnr to remain on the current queue, you should add the current queue as a destination.

```
<QueuePlaceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.0.4">
      <MultiQueuePlace>
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="35" Number="205" />
        <QueueIdentifier PseudoCityCode="7Q9I" PrefatoryInstructionCode="35" Number="206" />
      </MultiQueuePlace>
    </QueuePlaceRQ>
```